# How to prevent auto-generation of the @UpdateTimestamp in Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate, timestamp

I am using Spring Boot for creating the APIs and whenever I try to use the PUT end-point , the timestamp that is the `@UpdateTimestamp` gets the updated time automatically. I don't want the time to get updated when I change any other field except the status. The following is the Model.

```java
 @CreationTimestamp
 @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
 @Column(name = "start_time", updatable = false, nullable = false)
 Timestamp creationTime;

 @UpdateTimestamp
 @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
 @Column(name = "update_time")
 Timestamp updateTime;

 @Column(name = "first_name")
 String first_name;

 @Column(name = "last_name")
 String last_name;

 @Column(name = "age")
 String age;

 @Column(name = "mobile_number")
 String mobile_number;


 @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
 @Column(name = "status")
 private StatusEnum status;
```

The StatusEnum has

```
public enum StatusEnum {
    AVERAGE, FAIL , GOOD , EXCELLENT ;
}
```

When I try to update the age or mobile_number or any other field, the update_time automatically gets the present time (that is the time when it is getting updated), but I don't want the automatic updation. I want the `update_time` to change only when I update the status field . How can this be achieved ???
Thank you !

Comment: You could intercept entity changes with Hibernate event listeners. [This article](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-event-listeners/) completely explain how to do that. 
And this could help you too: [How to get updated fields](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/what-is-the-order-of-properties-when-calling-getdirtyproperties-from-postupdateevent/975)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want the time to get updated when I change any other field except the status.
>   ...
>   How can this be achieved?

You don't do this with `@UpdateTimestamp`.

The purpose of the `@UpdateTimestamp` to have a timestamp that gets updated whenever the entity gets saved no matter what changed.

As Dinar Zaripov wrote in the comments, the correct way to solve this is to write your own entity listener, get the list of updated fields as described here https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/what-is-the-order-of-properties-when-calling-getdirtyproperties-from-postupdateevent/975/2 and modify your entity accordingly.